# Consider the utility function U(x,y) = y√x

Tags: decision-theory

Draw the indifference curve for U= 10, U=15, U=20.

My knowledge of algebra has deteriorated over the last few years of being out of school and I am really unsure of how to answer this.

The X value is going up in the standard 1 to 10.

Comment: Hello! Could you try to make the title of your question more informative about what you are looking for? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: This suggests $y=\dfrac{U}{\sqrt{x}}$

so draw the three curves in the usual way

- $y=\dfrac{10}{\sqrt{x}}$; three of the points are $(1,10)$ and $(4,5)$ and $(9,3.333)$
- $y=\dfrac{15}{\sqrt{x}}$; three of the points are $(1,15)$ and $(4,7.5)$ and $(9,5)$
- $y=\dfrac{20}{\sqrt{x}}$; three of the points are $(1,20)$ and $(4,10)$ and $(9,6.667)$

Comment: Many thanks henry, this is correct! Was also wondering how you got to this answer from: U(x,y) = y√x. Why did you change the U over the square root of X? I'd love to know this for future reference.

Comment: @alz -  I divided both sides of $U=y \sqrt{x}$ by $\sqrt{x}$